# OS version capture script - unexpected results when using awk

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I have a small shell script as follows that I am using to login to multiple servers to capture whether the target server is using Redhat or Ubuntu as the OS version.

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ -f $HOME/osver.report.txt ];then
rm -rf $HOME/osver.report.txt
fi

for x in `cat hostlist`
do
OSVER=$(ssh $USER@${x} "cat /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null || grep -i DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null")
echo -e "$x \t\t $OSVER" >> osver.report.txt
done
```

The above script works, however, if I attempt to add in some awk as shown below and the server is a redhat server...my results in the osver.report.txt will only show the hostname and no OS version. I have played around with the quoting, but nothing seems to work.

```
 OSVER=$(ssh $USER@${x} "cat /etc/redhat-release | awk {'print $1,$2,$6,$7'} 2>/dev/null || grep -i DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null")
```

If I change the script as suggested to the following:

#!/bin/bash

if [ -f $HOME/osver.report.txt ];then
rm -rf $HOME/osver.report.txt
fi

for x in `cat hostlist`
do
OSVER=$(
   ssh $USER@${x} bash << 'EOF'
       awk '{print "$1,$2,$6,$7"}' /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null || grep -i DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null
   EOF
)
echo -e "$x \t\t $OSVER" >> osver.report.txt
done

Then I get the following errors:
   ./test.bash: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
   ./test.bash: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering from a quoting problem.  When you pass a quoted command to `ssh`, you effectively lose one level of quoting (as if you passed the same arguments to `sh -c "..."`).  So the command that you're running on the remote host is actually:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print ,,,}' | grep -i DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release
```

One way of resolving this is to pipe your script into a shell, rather than passing it as arguments:

```
OSVER=$(
ssh $USER@${x} bash <<'EOF'
awk '{print "$1,$2,$6,$7"}' /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null || 
grep -i DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null
EOF
)
```

The use of `<<'EOF'` here inhibits any variable expansion in the here document...without that, expressions like `$1` would be expanded locally.

---

A better solution would be to look into something like [ansible](https://ansible.com) which has built-in facilities for sshing to groups of hosts and collecting facts about them, including distribution version information.

Comment: shouldn't it be `'{print $1,$2,$6,$7}'`?

Comment: Thanks larsks. The one problem I am having with your solution is that it doesn't seem to be writing the result to a file.

Comment: Well, no. It's setting a variable (`$OSVER`), just like in the example you posted in your question.